# About TestRun: Unable to clone TestRuns from one TestCase or TestPlan to another in KIWI TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I do not know how to clone a TestRun to another TestCase.
Alternatively, I am not aware of how to clone TestRuns simultaneously when cloning a TestPlan or TestCase.

Description:
I am a novice user of KIWI TCMS and currently learning how to use this software. Following the instructions on the official website, I have successfully installed KIWI TCMS version 12.1. I have created a TestPlan that contains multiple TestCases. Each TestCase may have one or more TestRuns.

I have learned how to clone a TestPlan and all its TestCases. However, I have noticed that when cloning a TestPlan, the TestRuns associated with each TestCase are not cloned along with them. This means that every time I clone a TestPlan, I need to manually recreate all the TestRuns for each TestCase.

Additionally, I have tried to clone a TestRun, but it seems that I can only clone it within the same TestCase and not to other TestCases or TestPlans.

Requested help:

1. I would like to know if there is any way to clone the TestRuns along with the TestCases when cloning a TestPlan.
2. Is there any method to clone a TestRun from one TestCase to another or from a TestCase in one TestPlan to a TestCase in another TestPlan?

I appreciate any suggestions or information on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

================================================================================================================================

[Update Info]
I have carefully reviewed the documentation at https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/testrun.html#cloning-a-test-run and found a way to clone TestRuns from one TestCase to another in different TestPlans using the "Add Test Cases to an existing Test Run" section. However, this approach still requires manual cloning for each TestRun, which can be time-consuming and inefficient for large TestPlans with numerous TestCases.

Is there a more efficient method to clone an entire TestPlan, including all TestCases and their associated TestRuns, to a new TestPlan? For example, when there is a new firmware version that needs to be tested, it would be ideal to clone the entire TestPlan with all its TestCases and TestRuns to a new TestPlan for the updated version.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this in KIWI TCMS. Thank you!